# Wait for Twilio IVR call to finish to get the user response

Tags: node.js, express, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-studio

I've made an IVR using Twilio Studio. In my API I have something like this

```js
await validateForm(form);
await twilioIvrService(phone);
await saveData(form);

return res.json({message "Ok"})
```

Is there a way to wait for the `twilioIvrService` response? I mean, at the end of the IVR flow (on Twilio Studio) it should return a `value` (`Boolean`) depending on the user's choice, and `saveData` should store the form on a DB only if `value` is `true`. I want to get that `value` before calling `saveData`. The `form` parameter is almost 5KB.

This is how I run the Twilio flow using REST API Trigger

```js
const twilioIvrService = async (phone) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post(
      url,
      new URLSearchParams({
        To: phone,
        From: TWILIO_PHONE,
      }),
      {
        auth: {
          username: twilioAccountSid,
          password: twilioAuthToken,
        },
      },
    );

    console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the request that you make only triggers the Studio flow and return immedially.

I think it would be better if you provided a webhook that calls `saveData(form);` and add this webhook as the last step in your studio flow.

Comment: Do you mean using a "Make HTTP Request" widget at the end of the flow? The `form` parameter is almost 5KB, I think I can pass it via REST API Trigger and the widget can manage that. `saveData` should store the form on a DB only if the IVR response is successful

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Thanks, there's a problem with this. I want to send the same `body` the widget receives, so I've added `{{flow.data}}` on Request body, but when I want to `JSON.parse(data)` (on my API) it throws an error. The data I receive from the HTTP Request looks like this `{key=value, key=value}` (it's a string), the object doesn't have quotes in the key or in the value and can't be parsed (besides the equal sign instead of a colon). How can I send the full body ready to be parsed to an object?

Comment: It sounds like the request is "form URL encoded" but you should be able to [change the type](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/http-request#required-configuration-for-make-http-request) in the widget config.